# patch() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a test in which an object is updated using `patch`.

```
class Search(models.Model):
    id_search = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_user = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    .
    .
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
 def test_archive_search(self):

        user = User(id_user=75720912,
                    login='Client:75720912',
                )
        user.save()

        search = Search(
                        id_user=75720912,
                        .
                        .
                        archive=False
                )
        search.save()

        url = reverse('search-update', kwargs={'id_search':1})
        data = {'archive': True}
        response = self.client.patch(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

```
url(r'^search-update/(?P<id_search>\d+)$', SearchUpdateView.as_view(), name='search-update')
```

```
class SearchUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
    def get_object(self,id_search):
        return Search.objects.get(id_search=id_search)

    def patch(self, request):
        id_search = self.request.query_params.get('id_search', None)

        search_object = self.get_object(id_search=id_search)
        serializer = SearchSerializer(search_object, data=request.data, partial=True) 

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and get this error:

```
TypeError: patch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_search'
```

Interesting thing is that when the url was:

```
url(r'^search-update/$', SearchUpdateView.as_view(), name='search-update')
```

`SearchUpdateView` worked properly with given query params.

**EDIT**

I discovered that passing `id_search` to `patch` in view solves this problem when it comes to test, but it spoils working view.

```
class SearchUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
    def get_object(self, id_search):
        return Search.objects.get(id_search=id_search)

    def patch(self, request, id_search):
        #id_search = self.request.query_params.get('id_search', None) 


        search_object = self.get_object(id_search=id_search)
        serializer = SearchSerializer(search_object, data=request.data, partial=True) 

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Still I've got no idea how to bring it together.

Comment: You've defined the variable in your url pattern `(?P<id_search>\d+)` all named groups are passed as keyword arguments to the view. Your patch method needs to accept this parameter

Comment: @IainShelvington so how can i write a test with url in this form ''^search-update/$''? I tried it but couldn't find a way to pass id_search in query params.

Comment: I am not sure I remember correctly,  but if you define the url that way, the patch method will get the `id_search` param as a parameter,  as the error says.  Instead,  you are retrieving it as if it came as a query param, i.e. not part of the url path but as `search-update?id_search=`. Given you are passing `None` as a default when getting it, it works when you omit it

Comment: You can make `id_search` optional? `id_search=None` in the parameters and then you either use this value or get it from the query `id_search = id_search or self.request.query_params.get('id_search', None) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you define the url that way, the patch method will get the `id_search` param as a keyword argument,  as the error says.

Instead,  you are retrieving it as if it came as a query param, i.e. not part of the url path but as `search-update?id_search=`.

Given you are passing `None` as a default when getting it, it works when you omit it.

So choose which way you want to go.

In case the url definition is correct, then add the `id_search` argument to the signature of the patch method
and remove the code that retrieves it manually.

Or do both, as suggested in the comments above, by assigning a default value of None to the argument and retrieving it from the request if it is not part of the path

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was really clear. And what should I do in test to keep ```'^search-update/$'``` this url?

Comment: Do you mean removing the param? `url = reverse('search-update')`, i.e. avoid specifying it when building the url

Comment: But I need to specify id_user in url in test. Is there a way to do it not with kwarg?

Comment: Ok, I just had to build url in different way, not passing params to revert. ```url = '{base_url}?{querystring}.format(
            base_url=reverse('search-results'),
            querystring=query_params.urlencode()
        )```
where query_params is a ```QueryDict```
I got lost a bit.. thank you for help!